# Vue Router Guard Method still allowing page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I am using the following guard const to prevent user from entering pages while they don't have a token saved on cookies. However if i try it enough time  the user is able to enter the page but the components don't load, is is just a blank page

What else should i add to my router file to prevent this kind of thing from happening?

Here is my guard constant:

```
const guard = function(to, from, next) {
  const token = Cookies.get('token')
  if(typeof token === 'undefined' || token === null ){
    this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    window.location.href = "/";
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `next('/')` instead of `window.location.href = "/"` :

```
import store from 'path/to/store/
const guard = function(to, from, next) {
  const token = Cookies.get('token')
  if(typeof token === 'undefined' || token === null ){
   store.dispatch('logout');
    next('/');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Comment: it is also giving me the following error:
Cannot read property '$store' of undefined
But i declared my store in main.js

Comment: import it in th router file as you did in main.js `import store from 'path/to/store/`